# Firebase (Unity) RTDB Update Node Data Issue

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

If I update a node in Firebase RTDB using Unity with a RunTransaction passing in:

```
Dictionary<string, object> newData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
newData["key_a"] = "val_a";
newData["key_b"] = "val_b";
newData["key_c"] = "val_c";
mutableData.Value = newData;
```

With the node already having "key_d" with a value of "val_d" in it. RTDB seems to replace the entire node with the new data passed to it and get rid of "key_d".

My understanding is that "key_a", "key_b", "key_c" would be added but "key_d" would remain on the node.

When I test this in the editor this seems to be true but on real devices, it seems to override the whole node with just "key_a", "key_b", "key_c".

In the Firebase RTDB Security Rules, it states "newData represents the merged result of the new data being written and existing data." which I have some rules based on as well which again work for the editor but not on device.

Namely I validate writes with:
".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['key_a', 'key_b', 'key_c', 'key_d'])"

- Unity: 2021.3.9f1
- Firebase: 9.4.0

Tested on device with no errors, all data posting as normal from editor and device with logging. Tested in RTDB rules playground and data passed in behaves as expected with new keys being added with old keys remaining.

Any help or clarification would be much appreciated.

Edit: additional code:

```
db_reference
.Child("node")
.RunTransaction(RunTransaction)
.ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => {
    if (task.Exception != null) {
        Debug.Log("Transaction exception.");
    } else if (task.IsCompleted) {
        Debug.Log("Transaction complete.");
    }
});

TransactionResult RunTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
List<object> data = mutableData.Value as List<object>;
 if (data != null) {
   Dictionary<string, object> newData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
   newData["key_a"] = "val_a";
   newData["key_b"] = "val_b";
   newData["key_c"] = "val_c";
   mutableData.Value = newData; // this is where the node is overridden and the root of the question / clarification
 } else {
   Dictionary<string, object> newData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
   newData["key_a"] = "val_a";
   newData["key_b"] = "val_b";
   newData["key_c"] = "val_c";
   newData["key_d"] = "val_d";
   mutableData.Value = newData;
 }
 return TransactionResult.Success(mutableData);
}
```

Comment: None of the code you shared calls a Firebase API. Can you edit your question to show the minimal-but-complete/standalone code that we can run to reproduce the problem you are asking about?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen updated with a code snippet. I've tried different permutations of this. I've had all the keys creative via console first to rest if the node is overridden as well as a fresh node be created as if returns null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I get all the current data out of mutableData when data != null and combine that with any new data I wish to update with.

mutableData with newData is then returned into return TransactionResult.Success(mutableData) and all worked as it should.

If mutableData is saved missing any current data, that will be lost.